# Create streaming application on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to create streaming application on iPhone. I have gone through apple's developer forum already. What I want to do here is that I would be implementing my own streaming method. To start with I need to create an application which can get file from some URL using simple streaming and then will display in window (view). I cannot use browser here.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [this (HTTP Streaming)](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFHTTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) or [this (Apple live video streaming)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/iPhoneStreamingMediaOverview/iPhoneStreamingMediaOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH100-SW4) what you intend?

Http live stream (for videos) has been released with the 0S 3.0.

It's not clear if you are talking about video streaming or else.

Answer (score 0):

If it's audio streaming, check out this [cocoa with love article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html).
A lot of people use this as their starting point.